# TYPO3 version 6 to version 8 compatibility issues

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

While upgrading typo3 version 6 to 8.7.3 getting this database error...

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `pid` FROM `sys_template` WHERE (root = 1 AND deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0 AND starttime <= :starttime AND (endtime = 0 OR endtime > :endtime)) AND ((`sys_template`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`sys_template`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`sys_template`.`starttime` <= 1500543000) AND ((`sys_template`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`sys_template`.`endtime` > 1500543000)))': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':starttime AND (endtime = 0 OR endtime > :endtime)) AND ((`sys_template`.`delete' at line 1
```

Please review the screen shot.

[image: Error while upgrading the project]

[image: Getting the error while performing Database analyzer]

Comment: Have you done the Database Compare in the Install Tool?

Comment: Yes first i have update it to v7 and now in v8. Yes performed the Database Analyzer from the INSTALL tool.

Comment: is ext:dbal still installed?

Comment: is the field "pid" still present in table "sys_template"?

Comment: I had this problem after v8 update, too, for me it turned out that DB compare wasn't finalized.

Comment: Yes extension dbl and adodb both are installed ( should i have to remove it ? ) Yes, pid still present in `sys_template` table ( should i also remove it ? ).

Comment: Yes, v8 now works with doctrine, dbal and adodb are deprecated and should not be installed!

Comment: no, pid should definitely stay!

Comment: Yes removed those extension as well as from `PackageStates.php` file too.

Comment: and does it work now?

Comment: Still not working ... I have add one image in the description section which shows the error...

Comment: ok, uninstall powermail and run DB compare again

Comment: Error remains same ... No any changes while uninstall powermail...

Comment: perhaps you should downgrade to v7 again, do the DB compare again and update then again...

Comment: I have the v7 database in my backup; so i have also do that and did the DB compare again and again. I executed the error in sql command line and gives the error as `Error in query (1064): Syntax error near ':starttime AND (endtime = 0 OR endtime > :endtime)) AND ((`sys_template`.`delete' at line 1 `

Comment: OK, maybe i know what's up: please check wether your credentials point to the right DB!

Comment: Is this solution working for you now? If so, please condider marking this question as answered.

Comment: Yess definitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB Configuration variables have changed from TYPO3 v7 to v8 ^^

It is not

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['database']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['host']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['username']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['password']`

anymore, but

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['Connections']['Default']['host']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['Connections']['Default']['dbname']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['Connections']['Default']['user']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['Connections']['Default']['password']`

This is especially the case, when configuring additional Environments via AdditionalConfiguration.php